# Django error: cannot cast type date to time without time zone

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

Please help me with this error:

```
File "/Users/ecommerce/proshopvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", 
line 84, in _execute

return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type date to time without time zone
LINE 1: ..." ALTER COLUMN "createdAt" TYPE time USING "createdAt"::time


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
"a lot of code, and:"

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type date to time without time zone
LINE 1: ..." ALTER COLUMN "createdAt" TYPE time USING "createdAt"::time
```

In models i have:

```
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and how i understand from docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/

"The auto_now and auto_now_add options will always use the date in the default timezone at the moment of creation or update."

But zone doesn't create, or error in something else, i creating new database, so i can delete all tables

Maybe there is step in django where it initials time zone?

Readed this topic [postgreSQL alter column data type to timestamp without time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059108/postgresql-alter-column-data-type-to-timestamp-without-time-zone/43083187) and many others but can't fix it to 'migrate' without errors

Comment: Make sure You have a line in your setting.py which looks like this `TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'`

Comment: The issue is this: `ALTER COLUMN "createdAt" TYPE time USING "createdAt"::time"`. Something is trying to alter the `type` of your `createdAt` field away from some form of `date`(I presume) to a `time` type. That is not what you want. You need to track down what is doing this.

Comment: TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata' - i tried this also

Comment: I think there is problem with  modifying `date` to `time` without `time zone`

Answer (score 3):

Yes there a problem modifying a `date` to `time` with or without time zone. The problem being that in Postgres date does not have a time component so any successful attempt to get time results in '00:00:00'. Try

```
select current_date::timestamp::time;
```

Given that then assuming your objective is the change the type then just drop and re-add the column;

```
alter table test_table drop createdat;
alter table test_table add  createdat time  default '00:00:00'::time;
```

Of course I have never figured out what good time is without the date. Which came first, '10:15:00' or '11:15:00'? Well if 10:15 was today and 11:15 was yesterday then 11:15 came first. Unless you define it as hours-since-midnight. So perhaps a better option:

```
alter table test_table 
      alter column createdat 
               set data type timestamp 
             using createdat::timestamp;
```

See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ee8fe598422f2bff4c9b6b3e7de4b324) Yes, timestamp takes more space, but is much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

First i want say Thanks to Belayer, but have no rating to vote for his answer

I needed to Alter columns from type "date" to make them "timestamp with time zone", because my Django models configuration wanted to be them like this `createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

so i run `alter table "base_product" alter column "createdAt" type timestamp with time zone;`

But there was strange thing for me, all tables where there was type "date" modifyed to "timestamp with time zone" (it was good, because there where few other places where i need that), but only not in table "base_product" where i run query, and also didn't want to modify it automatically any more

so then i run `ALTER TABLE "base_product" ALTER COLUMN "createdAt" DROP DEFAULT, ALTER COLUMN "createdAt" TYPE timestamp with time zone USING timestamp with time zone 'epoch' + "createdAt", ALTER COLUMN "createdAt" SET DEFAULT now();`

i read that from postgres docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case what a did was, delete de migrations to start from where all work fine, then I delete the field, apply a migrations and then a Added like a new column. And it works. Doing it in that way the django doesn't know tha instead of alter a column, he think that I create a new one.